# Nobel prize for (dangerous) LED lamps?

Tags: visible-light, semiconductor-physics, biophysics, light-emitting-diodes

There are many scientific articles about the danger of LED lamps (see below from the LED magazine, from scientific american, from a governmental journal and from Harvard health newsletter):

- [Light and human health: LED risks highlighted](http://www.ledsmagazine.com/articles/2010/11/light-and-human-health-led-risks-highlighted.html)
- [The Dark Side of LED Lightbulbs](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/led-lightbulb-concerns/)
- [Hidden Blue Hazard? LED Lighting and Retinal Damage in Rats](http://ehp.niehs.nih.gov/122-a81/)
- [Blue light has a dark side](http://www.health.harvard.edu/newsletters/harvard_health_letter/2012/may/blue-light-has-a-dark-side)

Now after the Nobel prize has been announced, LED lamps are praised allover the news.

I want to understand, are the articles on the danger of LED lamps just junk papers?
Or that there are different kinds of LED lamps? Or that the prize was not about lamps exactly?

What is going on here?

Comment: Could you link at least one of the articles you are talking about?

Comment: You mean there is a lot of pseudoscientific hype about the dangers of virtually everything out there? Yes, there is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I will give me a few minutes

Comment: See for example this article from [one of Britains more reputable and least sensationalist newspapers](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2324325/Do-environmentally-friendly-LED-lights-cause-BLINDNESS.html). In case the irony is not obvious, an LED bulb may damage your eye if you look at it from a distance of 1cm for several hours.

Comment: See [this related post on the Skeptics SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17572/)

Comment: There is a natural light source that will cause retinal damage in a few minutes: it's main sequence star called Sol. We generally discourage kids to look at it directly. Some listen, some don't.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about physics concepts at all. It might be ok on [sustainability.se], [skeptics.se] or [biology.se]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about safety and biology, not physics.